# Cleaning dataset. If cell contains "<" do X if ">" do Y with function or apply. Want all columns to only contain floats

Tags: python, pandas

1. My dataframe contains 88 columns (elements) which will ideally contain floats. But the data has some things which need cleaning. I have toyed with the idea of iterrows() but Ive read on here that people suggest not using this and using functions and applying to the df for efficiency. The 3 main issues I want to resolve are:

- BDL = below detection limit -->  replace with NA
- "<"                         -->  remove the < symbol, then half the remaining value in the cell
- ">"                         -->  remove the > symbol

sample data:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Be_ppm         |     Bi_ppm       |         Ca_ppm   |     Cd_ppm       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          <0.1       |         0.08     |      217         |       >1000      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

What I would like to return:

```
    |---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
    |      Be_ppm         |     Bi_ppm       |         Ca_ppm   |     Cd_ppm       |
    |---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
    |          0.05       |         0.08     |      217         |        1000      |
    |---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I have been trying to write code which is based upon the following pseudo-code:

```py
import pandas as pd

def less_than(cell):    
    if cell contains "<":
        remove "<" from string
        cell convert to float
        cell = cell/2
    return cell


def more_than(cell)
    if cell contains ">":
        remove ">" from string
        cell convert to float            
    return cell

#then I think I can execute the function across the df? 
df = df.apply(less_than, axis=1)
```

When doing this it applies on the row and not the cell, how would I achieve this? Is this the best approach?

2. When exploring the df, is there a quick way to return rows which contain string/symbols?

Comment: Please provide sample df an expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Be_ppm': ['<0.1'],
    'B1_ppm': [.08],
    'Ca_ppm': [217],
    'Cd_ppm': ['>1000'],
})

def convert(val):
    if isinstance(val, int):
        return float(val)
    elif isinstance(val, float):
        return val
    elif val[0] == '>':
        return float(val[1:])
    return float(val[1:]) / 2

print(df.applymap(convert))
```

Output:

```
   Be_ppm  B1_ppm  Ca_ppm  Cd_ppm
0    0.05    0.08   217.0  1000.0
```

Here's one way to find rows that don't contain a numeric type:

```py
df[~df.applymap(pd.api.types.is_number).all(axis=1)]
```

Comment: thanks! I didnt know about applymap before and have been adjusting this method slightly with some other errors with empty cells. Do you know a way of returning rows in a df which contain string/symbols?

Comment: @polecat You're welcome. Please confirm if my updated post answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, just for anything else who does come by this, it halved every value but for only the values which contain ">" to be halved is done by this:

```
def convert(val):
      if isinstance(val, int):
          return float(val)
     elif isinstance(val, float):
         return val
     elif val[0] == '>':
         val = float(val[1:])
         return val
     elif val[0] == '<':
         val = float(val[1:])
         return val/2
```

Comment: What's the point to rewrite the same @Balaji Ambresh answer?

Comment: Hi rpanai, thankyou. I have altered the formula to halve only values which contain '<', the answer kindly provided by @balaji halved all values when run